# Create a new column with letters following the number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, letter

I would like to create a new column with letters, following the number of rows in the data frame.

Data:

```
set.seed(42)
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
df
            X1         X2
1   1.37095845  1.3048697
2  -0.56469817  2.2866454
3   0.36312841 -1.3888607
4   0.63286260 -0.2787888
5   0.40426832 -0.1333213
6  -0.10612452  0.6359504
7   1.51152200 -0.2842529
8  -0.09465904 -2.6564554
9   2.01842371 -2.4404669
10 -0.06271410  1.3201133
```

I could insert letters by setting the number of rows manually. I would like to do set it accordingly to the number of rows in the data frame.

```
df$label = as.character(LETTERS[1:10])
df
            X1         X2 label
1   1.37095845  1.3048697     A
2  -0.56469817  2.2866454     B
3   0.36312841 -1.3888607     C
4   0.63286260 -0.2787888     D
5   0.40426832 -0.1333213     E
6  -0.10612452  0.6359504     F
7   1.51152200 -0.2842529     G
8  -0.09465904 -2.6564554     H
9   2.01842371 -2.4404669     I
10 -0.06271410  1.3201133     J
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `seq_len` with `nrow`, but works only up to 26 rows.

```
df$label <-  LETTERS[seq_len(nrow(df))]
```

In case you have more rows and want to repeat `LETTEERS`:

```
df$label <- LETTERS[1 + seq(0, length.out = nrow(df)) %% 26]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works really well. Is it possible to pipe the command with ```dplyr```?

Comment: I don't use `dplyr`. Maybe ask a new question for a `dplyr` answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Following your answer, I just found the ```dplyr``` solution. But, it's limited to 26.

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(label = LETTERS[row_number()])
```